# Multiple tsconfig.json - refer to other Types, but do not include them with compile

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, tsconfig

I have the following structure:

```
General\tsconfig.json (out: General\general.js)
General\Example\ExampleA.ts
General\Example\ExampleB.ts

Other\tsconfig (out: Other\other.js)
Other\Example\ExampleC.ts
```

In **general.js** I expect *ExampleA* and *ExampleB* compiled and in **other.js** I'd like to just see *ExampleC* compiled.

When I refer to other.js in HTML I make sure I've always general.js loaded first.

I use seperate tsconfig files for this, but ExampleC doesn't see the types ExampleA and B.

When I add an `include` with the path to General, then all the files of General are also compiled within other.js.

Is there an option in between? Refer to the types of the other files but not include them in the generated outFile?

Comment: Hi, I want to do something similar. Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an option in between? Refer to the types of the other files
>   but not include them in the generated outFile?

You can compile files in `General` first, in a separate compilation, and add `declaration:true` to `tsconfig.json` (or `-d` flag to tsc). Then compiler will generate declaration file, `general.d.ts`, along with `general.js`. That `.d.ts` file [will contain only types](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html) from `General`, which should be enough to compile any code that depends on `General`.

Then you can include `general.d.ts` in `tsconfig.json` in `Other`.